# "They are never" or "They never"?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, contractions

Which one is correct in English language? For example:

> Oh no, they are never gonna stop!

or

> Oh no, they never gonna stop!

Comment: The _are_ goes with the  _gonna_;  _are_ is an auxiliary verb and negatives like _never_ go after the first auxiliary verb.

Comment: @luiz_eldorado "they never gonna..." https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=They+re+never+gonna%2CThey+never+gonna%2CThey+are+never+gonna&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThey%20never%20gonna%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

In this case "are never" is correct. Or "they're never gonna stop." I prefer not to use "gonna"; I use "going to" instead.

Comment: "Oh no, they never stop" is also possible depending on what you want to convey.